# How to Convert Solutions which is in VS 2010 to VS 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

How to Convert VS 2010 Solution to VS 2013 without changing the Target .net Version

Comment: Just open it in Visual Studio 2013 and it will do anything for you...

Comment: What the problem? Did you try to open it in visual studio 2013 at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the solution using VS2013.
It will be converted, but the .net version won't be changed.

If you want to change .net version you can do it in the project configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Simply opening it in VS 2013 will convert it without changes to .NET version, but you have to have the original version of .NET Framework installed.